# How can I find the segmentation fault in this c code?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault

When I run the program it outputs:

`Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`
and I can't find the problem.

I tried debugging it, but I don't have enough experience in c, to find the bug.

What the code supposed to do, is firstly create a tree randomly and then sum up the values of all nodes.

Also I really need to know how to write safer c code, without segmentation faults and that kind of problems.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


/**
 * Tree structure, where there can be any number of children
 */
typedef struct Tree {

    /**
     * Value of current node
     */
    double value;

    /**
     * number of children
     */
    int n;

    /**
     * children
     */
    struct Tree **children;
} Tree;


Tree *create(double value, int n) {
    Tree *tree = (Tree*) malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    int i;

    *tree = (Tree) {
        .value = value,
        .n = n,
        .children = NULL
    };

    if (n) {
        tree->children = (Tree**) malloc(sizeof(Tree*));

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tree->children[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    return tree;
}


Tree *make_random_tree(int height) {
    double value;
    int n, i;
    Tree *tree;

    value = (rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * 100.0;
    n = rand() % 10;


    if (height == 0) {
        return create(value, 0);
    }

    tree = create(value, n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       tree->children[i] = make_random_tree(height - 1);
    }

    return tree;
}


void delete(Tree *tree) {
    int i;

    if (tree == NULL) return;

    for (i = 0; i < tree->n; i++) {
        delete(tree->children[i]);
    }

    free(tree->children);
    free(tree);
}


double sum_tree_values(Tree *tree) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    int i;

    if (tree == NULL) return 0.0;

    sum += tree->value;
    for (i = 0; i < tree->n; i++) {
        sum += sum_tree_values(tree->children[i]);
    }

    return sum;
}


int main() {
    Tree *tree = make_random_tree(3);


    delete(tree);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to run the code in a debugger, so you can see which source line the segmentation fault is occurring on?  If you are on Linux, merely (1) add the `-g` flag when compiling, (2) invoke `gdb myprogram`, and (3) type `run`.  Your program should run, but now, when it crashes, `gdb` should show you what line it was on.  And typing `bt` should give you a stack backtrace, showing what function calls got you to that point.

Comment: Look up "valgrind", it is going to save you a lot of time.

Comment: Side note: When one of the regulars here finds your problem in less than a minute, that's how they did it.  They didn't inspect your code line by line and detect the error with their IR vision and rad skillz — they "cheated", and copy-pasted your code to their machine, and compiled and ran it with their compiler and their debugger, and that's how they found the problem.  ("Let the computer do the dirty work", aka "Laziness is a virtue".)  But that's why people here are always so insistent that code be posted as text, not images.

Comment: Hint: How much memory is allocated by `malloc(sizeof(Tree*))`? If you treat the returned pointer as an array, how many elements will it have?

Comment: When I compile with GCC with options `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined`, I get this memory access error: `WRITE of size 8 at 0x602000000018 thread T0` `#0 0x558d513385e3 in create /home/main.c:42`
`#1 0x558d513386d1 in make_random_tree /home/main.c:63`
`#2 0x558d51338d35 in main /home/main.c:103`
...
`0x602000000018 is located 0 bytes to the right of 8-byte region [0x602000000010,0x602000000018)`
`allocated by thread T0 here:`
...
`#1 0x558d5133848e in create /home/main.c:39`
`#2 0x558d513386d1 in make_random_tree /home/main.c:63`
`#3 0x558d51338d35 in main /home/main.c:103`
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is caused by accessing memory which doesn't belong to you. Consider using [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) for finding these bugs

In:

```
Tree *create(double value, int n) {
    Tree *tree = (Tree*) malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    int i;

    *tree = (Tree) {
        .value = value,
        .n = n,
        .children = NULL
    };

    if (n) {
        tree->children = (Tree**) malloc(sizeof(Tree*));

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tree->children[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    return tree;
}
```

You loop over `n` children and set them to `NULL` but you just allocate 1 child. You have to allocate space for all children:

change:

```
tree->children = (Tree**) malloc(sizeof(Tree*));
```

to:

```
tree->children = (Tree**) malloc(n * sizeof(Tree*));
```

furthermore consider using `calloc` instead of `malloc` it will automaticly set all children to `NULL`.

so instead of:

```
if (n) {
        tree->children = (Tree**) malloc(n * sizeof(Tree*));

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tree->children[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
```

use:

```
if (n)
    tree->children = (Tree**) calloc(n, sizeof(Tree*));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!